# Regular expression for matching exact word affect the special character matching

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replaces the special characters from word selected by user.

I have written the code as

```
var name = "and";
var text = "viverra*.and standard'android viverra'.Vivamus (sit amet felis) scelerisque) ullamcorper (erat) eu mat)tis lorem.";
name = name.replace(new RegExp(/\[(.*?')\]/g), '');
var escaped= name.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$&")
var regexp = new RegExp("\\b(" + escaped + ")\\b", "g");
console.log(text.replace(regexp, "_$&_"));
```

It gives correct output for exact word as,

```
viverra*._and_ standard'android viverra'.Vivamus (sit amet felis) scelerisque) ullamcorper (erat) eu mat)tis lorem.
```

But when user select

```
name=(sit amet felis) scelerisque) or (erat) or viverra' or viverra*.
```

It does replace special characters.

When I write the line 5 as

```
var regexp = new RegExp(escaped, "g");
```

It will remove all special characters but does not match the exact word & gives the output for "and" as,

```
viverra*._and_ st_and_ard'_and_roid viverra'.Vivamus (sit amet felis) scelerisque) ullamcorper (erat) eu mat)tis lorem.
```

Please help me. I want to replace special character and also want to match the exact word....

Comment: really very intelligent question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add, after the escaping:

```
var escaped= name.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$&");

// 2 lines to add:
escaped = escaped.replace(/^(\w)/, "\\b$1");
escaped = escaped.replace(/(\w)$/, "$1\\b");

var regexp = new RegExp(escaped, "g");
```

This will add the word boundary only when it's usefull.