# Javascript regular expression for matching whole words including special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match whole exact words using a javascript regular expression.

Given the strings: 1) "I know C++." and 2) "I know Java."

I have tried using `new Regex('\\b' + text + '\\b', 'gi')` and that works great for words without special characters like example #2.

I've also taken a look at this url:
[Regular expression for matching exact word affect the special character matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232987/regular-expression-for-matching-exact-word-affect-the-special-character-matching)

and implemented the:

`escaped = escaped.replace(/^(\w)/, "\\b$1");
escaped = escaped.replace(/(\w)$/, "$1\\b");`

and that will match `text = 'C++'` (it will match both examples)

However, if someone types a typo, and the string is "I know C++too.", the latter regex will still match the C++ when I don't want it to because the word "C++too" is not an exact match for `text = 'C++'`.

What changes can I make so that it will not match unless C++ is both the front of the word and the end of the word.

Comment: So you want to match words and the string `"C++"`? Or something more general?

Comment: `new RegExp('\\b' + 'I know C\\+\\+' + '(?!\\w)', 'gi')`

Comment: something more general.  if text = "C++", i want it to match "I know C++." but not "I know C++too."

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u18s4pzL/ first - yes, second - no.

Comment: @changus Do you want to match those entire strings, or just each word? What would the desired output be for `"test A+B"` or `"I knowC++"`? What is the larger program that you want to do this for?

Comment: Can you post the whole javascript code that you used?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "word"?

Comment: @qxz - The larger program I am trying to do is highlight words in a string.  Say the word I want to highlight is "C++" in the string, "I know C++, and John knows C++too."  I want it to highlight the first instance of C++ but not the second because it is not a exact word match of C++ because it is "C++too", whereas it will match the first one, but ignore the comma.

Answer (score 1):

If `whole words including special characters` means everything **but** `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`, you can simply do:

```js
const REGEX = /([^\s]+)+/g;
```

```js
function selectWords(string) {
  const REGEX = /([^\s]+)+/g;
  
  return string
  
    // remove punctuation
    .replace(/[^a-z0-9\s+#]/ig, "")
  
    // perform the match
    .match(REGEX)

    // prevent null returns
    || []
  ;
}

var text = "Hello World"
var [first, second, ...rest] = selectWords(text);
console.log(1, {first, second, rest});


// example with punctuation
var text = "I can come today, she said, but not tomorrow."
var [first, second, third, ...rest] = selectWords(text);
console.log(2, {first, second, third, rest});


// example with possible throw
var text = ",.'\"`  \r"
var [first, second, third, ...rest] = selectWords(text);
console.log(3, {first, second, third, rest});

// example with a specific word to be matched
function selectSpecificWord(string, ...words) {
  return selectWords(string)
    .filter(word => ~words.indexOf(word))
  ;
}
var expected = "C++";
var test = "I know C++";
var test1 = "I know C++AndJava";

console.log("Test Case 1", selectSpecificWord(test, expected));
console.log("Test Case 2", selectSpecificWord(test1, expected));
```

Comment: i need an example that takes in a variable "text" into the regex

Comment: (Edited) You can check it out clicking on `Run code snippet` button at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a range of accepted characters(`[+#]`) after word characters:

```js
str = 'I know C++too. I know Java and C#.';
console.log(str.match(/(\w[+#]+|\w+)/g));
```

NB: `\w[+#]+` must be placed first in the alternation expression to take precedence over the more generic  `\w+`.

Comment: i need an example that takes in a variable "text" into the regex

Answer (score 0):

Use this `((?:(?:\w)+?)(?=\b|\w[-+]{2,2})(?:[-+]{2,2})?)`

I've included a `-` symbol for an example also. See it [in life](https://regex101.com/r/vFBCA4/1).

[image]

Comment: `(?:\w)` is the same as `\w`. `{2,2}` is the same as `{2}`.